# Replacing unknown number of named groups

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am working on such a pattern:

```
<type>"<prefix>"<format>"<suffix>";<neg_type>"<prefix>"<format>"<suffix>"
```

So i wrote 2 examples here, with or without prefix:

```
n"prefix"#,##0"suffix";-"prefix"#,##0"suffix"
n#,##0"suffix";-#,##0"suffix"
```

Indeed i wrote the folowing regex to capture my group:

```
raw = r"(?P<type>^.)(?:\"(?P<prefix>[^\"]*)\"){0,1}(?P<format>[^\"]*)(?:\"(?P<suffix>[^\"]*)\"){0,1};(?P<negformat>.)(?:\"(?P=prefix)\"){0,1}(?P=format)(?:\"(?P=suffix)\"){0,1}"
```

Now i am parsing a big text which contain such structure and i would like to replace the prefix or suffix (only if they exist!). Due to the unknown number (potentially null) of captured group i do not know how to easily can make my replacements (with re.sub).

Additionnaly, due to some implementation constraint i treat sequentially prefix and suffix (so i do not get the suffix to replace at the same time than the prefix to replace even if they belong to the same sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we can simplify your regex by using single quotes for the string. That removes the necessity of escaping the `"` character. Second, `{0,1}` can be replaced by `?`:

```
raw = r'(?P<type>^.)(?:"(?P<prefix>[^"]*)")?(?P<format>[^"]*)(?:"(?P<suffix>[^"]*)")?;(?P<negformat>.)(?:"(?P<prefix2>(?P=prefix))")?(?P=format)(?:"(?P<suffix2>(?P=suffix))")?'
```

Notice that I have added `(?P<prefix2>)` and `(?P<suffix2)` named groups above for the second occurrences of the prefix and suffix.

I am working on the assumption that your pattern may be repeated within the text (if the pattern only appears once, this code will still work). In that case, the character substitutions must be made from the last to first occurrence so that the `start` and `last` character offset information returned by the regex engine remains correct even after character substitutions are made. Similarly, when we find an occurrence of the pattern, we must first replace in the order `suffix2`, `prefix2`, `suffix` and `prefix`.

We use `re.finditer` to iterate through the text to return `match` objects and form these into a `list`, which we reverse so that we can process the last matches first:

```
import re

raw = r'(?P<type>^.)(?:"(?P<prefix>[^"]*)")?(?P<format>[^"]*)(?:"(?P<suffix>[^"]*)")?;(?P<negformat>.)(?:"(?P<prefix2>(?P=prefix))")?(?P=format)(?:"(?P<suffix2>(?P=suffix))")?'

s = """a"prefix"format"suffix";b"prefix"format"suffix"
x"prefix_2"format_2"suffix_2";y"prefix_2"format_2"suffix_2"
"""
new_string = s

matches = list(re.finditer(raw, s, flags=re.MULTILINE))
matches.reverse()
if matches:
    for match in matches:
        if match.group('suffix2'):
            new_string = new_string[0:match.start('suffix2')] + 'new_suffix' + new_string[match.end('suffix2'):]
        if match.group('prefix2'):
            new_string = new_string[0:match.start('prefix2')] + 'new_prefix' + new_string[match.end('prefix2'):]
        if match.group('suffix'):
            new_string = new_string[0:match.start('suffix')] + 'new_suffix' + new_string[match.end('suffix'):]
        if match.group('prefix'):
            new_string = new_string[0:match.start('prefix')] + 'new_prefix' + new_string[match.end('prefix'):]
print(new_string)
```

Prints:

```
a"new_prefix"format"new_suffix";b"new_prefix"format"new_suffix"
x"new_prefix"format_2"new_suffix";y"new_prefix"format_2"new_suffix"
```

The above code, for demo purposes, makes the same substitutions for each occurrence of the pattern.

As far as your second concern:

There is nothing preventing you from making two passes against the text, once to replace the prefixes and once to replace suffixes as these become know. Obviously, you would only be checking certain groups for each pass, but you could still be using the same regex. And, of course, for each occurrence of the pattern you can have unique substitutions. The above code shows how to find and make the substitutions.

**To allow 0 to 9 instances or the prefix**

```
import re

raw = r'(?P<type>^.)(?:"(?P<prefix>[^"]*)")?(?P<format>[^"]*)(?:"(?P<suffix>[^"]*)")?;(?P<negformat>.)(?P<prefix2>(?:"(?P=prefix)"){0,9})(?P=format)(?:"(?P<suffix2>(?P=suffix))")?'

s = """a"prefix"format"suffix";b"prefix""prefix""prefix"format"suffix"
x"prefix_2"format_2"suffix_2";y"prefix_2"format_2"suffix_2"
"""
new_string = s

matches = list(re.finditer(raw, s, flags=re.MULTILINE))
matches.reverse()
if matches:
    for match in matches:
        if match.group('suffix2'):
            new_string = new_string[0:match.start('suffix2')] + 'new_suffix' + new_string[match.end('suffix2'):]
        if match.group('prefix2'):
            start = match.start('prefix2')
            end = match.end('prefix2')
            repl = s[start:end]
            n = repl.count('"') // 2
            new_string = new_string[0:start] + (n * '"new_prefix"') + new_string[end:]
        if match.group('suffix'):
            new_string = new_string[0:match.start('suffix')] + 'new_suffix' + new_string[match.end('suffix'):]
        if match.group('prefix'):
            new_string = new_string[0:match.start('prefix')] + 'new_prefix' + new_string[match.end('prefix'):]
print(new_string)
```

Prints:

```
a"new_prefix"format"new_suffix";b"new_prefix""new_prefix""new_prefix"format"new_suffix"
x"new_prefix"format_2"new_suffix";y"new_prefix"format_2"new_suffix"
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Ronald for your detail answer; if i understand well i have to always form new named groups depending of the number of occurences of repetitions. As an exemple if raw = r"(?P<type>^.)(?:\"(?P<prefix>[^\"]*)\"){0,9}(?P<format>[^\"]*)(?:\"(?P<suffix>[^\"]*)\"){0,9};(?P<negformat>.)(?:\"(?P=prefix)\"){0,9}(?P=format)(?:\"(?P=suffix)\"){0,9}"
i would have to do 10 prefix named groups ?

Comment: @amous You could do (?P<prefix2>(?:\"(?P=prefix)\"){0,9}) to name all 0 to 9 occurrences and if the prefix2 group appears n times (it should not be difficult to figure out what n is by scanning the string for " characters), then the whole match can be replaced by n * '"new_prefix"'. I have updated the answer to add additional code to demonstrate this.